# Can we disable the drag window to top of screen Mission Control / Spaces feature in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, spaces, window-manager, mission-control

> Open Mission Control
>
> Use any of these methods to open Mission Control:
>
> ....
>
> - In OS X El Capitan, drag a window to the top of the screen.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100

I'm using a window snapping/resizing app and this feature above, introduced in El Capitan, is being triggered instead. This when I snap a window to the center top of the screen.

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 27):

According to the Reddit thread, [Is there any way to disable Mission Control coming up when I drag a window to the top of the screen?](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3nj42i/is_there_any_way_to_disable_mission_control/), the solution is:

> System Preferences > Mission Control
>
> Uncheck "Displays have separate Spaces" then log out and back in again.

It works, I had the same issue & now it's sorted.

Answer (score 7):

> Haven't found out how to disable just the window drag activation but
>   you can turn it off entirely with:
>
> Disable:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool TRUE && killall Dock
> ```
>
> Enable:
>
> ```
> defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled && killall Dock
> ```

[source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7300027?answerId=31716668022#31716668022)

Comment: Note to other people trying this, this will disable the full screen apps manager entirely, meaning you cannot use ^up to open it or the pinch in gesture.

Comment: This does not seem to do anything on macOS Ventura

Answer (score 0):

As per the Better touch tool config explanation about using it in conjunction with spaces:

`defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 2.0; killall Dock`

delays the opening of the spaces switcher, allowing for the window resize to take place.